# Excel VBA: get value of cell, independent of cell's formatting

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, `Range("A1").Value` should return the underlying value of the range A1 on the worksheet.  But I'm getting a different value if the cell is formatted as Accounting.

How do I get the actual underlying value of the cell?

**Worksheet**

Make a new document, enter the following values in cells:

- A1: 0.00001
- A2: =A1
- A3: =A1=A2

As you'd expect, A3 results in `TRUE`.  Now change the formatting of A2 to Accounting, using 2 decimal places.  A2 now reads `$ 0.00`, but the underlying value is still `0.00001`, so A3 is still `TRUE`.

**VBA**

Make a new module and add in the following function:

```
Function f(addr As String)
    f = Range(addr).Value
End Function
```

As you can see, this just gets the value of a range using the `Value` method of the `Range` object.

**Worksheet**

Back to the worksheet.  Enter the following values:

- B1: =f("A1")
- B2: =f("A2")
- B3: =B1=B2

`A1` and `A2` have the same underlying value, but `B1` and `B2` don't, even though they're both calculated using the `Value` method of `A1` and `A2`.

The expression in `A3` (`=A1=A2`) is accessing the actual underlying value of `A1` and `A2`.  How do I access these values in VBA?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010, and `B3` is definitely coming up `FALSE`.

Comment: Guess it doesn't recalc if you only change the formatting...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It initally came up TRUE for me as well because I added the formatting after I entered the formulas.

To repro - re-edit B2.

To get the underlying value you need to use the VALUE2 property which seems to ignore the formatting:

```
Function f(addr As String)
    f = Range(addr).Value2
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue with using VBA and Value with currency formatted cells beyond 4 decimals points is covered well by [this post at Dick's blog](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/10/08/the-currency-format/)

> If you type a number into an unformatted cell in Excel, that number is
>   stored in the Double data type. When you format that number, you show
>   it in a specific way, but you don’t change the number. For instance,
>   if you format the number 1 as a Comma style, you get 1.00. The
>   underlying data is still a 1, you’re just showing it differently. The
>   Date format and the Currency format are two exceptions to this rule.
>
> When you format something as a Date or Currency, you actually change
>   the underlying data type (of the value stored in the Value property).
>   When it comes to the Date format, this is semantics because you can
>   switch between the Date and Double data types without any change to
>   the data. Not so much with the Currency data type. Currency **only
>   supports four decimal places**, so jamming a Double with, say, five
>   decimals into a Currency data type will result in a different number.